# types/value length mismatch (argument="tuple", value='myAddress'

Tags: javascript, solidity

I'm having some problem with the arguments of a function written in solidity and called in JavaScript. I'm using the Remix ballot default example, except I removed the first require in it. It looks like this:

```
function giveRightToVote(address voter) public {
    require(
        !voters[voter].voted,
        "The voter already voted."
    );
    require(voters[voter].weight == 0);
    voters[voter].weight = 1;
}
```

As far as I'm understanding, I should give it an address so it can give permission to that address. This is the JavaScript code that calls that function:

```
const permission = async () => {
    const ethereumAddress = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(account);
    const gasEstimate = await window.contract.methods.giveRightToVote([ethereumAddress]).estimateGas({ from: account });
    console.log("1");
    const result = await window.contract.methods.giveRightToVote(account).send({ gas: gasEstimate, from: account});
    document.getElementById("permissionArea").innerHTML = "Permiso para votar obtenido";
    /**
    await window.contract.methods.giveRightToVote(account).send({ from: account });
    document.getElementById("permissionArea").innerHTML = "Permiso para votar obtenido";
    */
}
```

The last commented part was the original code. I have changed it a lot trying to make it work. I kind of guess the problem is the argument account. I have tried using [account] which has worked in another function, but I seem to not be able to figure out how it wants the parameters. I know the account is right, I get it like this:

```
const accounts = await ethereum.request({method: "eth_requestAccounts"});
account = accounts[0];
```

And when I print it it's the right address. The full error reads:

```
Error: types/value length mismatch (argument="tuple", value=["0x40bCba26F1ED151Fa34232E3CFf55d9C2867bCf1"], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

I'm still confused that it wants a tuple when the smart contract only takes one argument.

Comment: I have this same problem with the vote function as well. It gave me the same problem but  I got away with it giving it an array: 
`let numero = new Uint8Array(1);`
`numero[0]=selectedCandidate;`
`await window.contract.methods.vote(numero).send({ gas: gasEstimate, from: account });`
It gave me a different error:
`MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. {`
`caught (in promise) Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. {`